UDP Message Sending and Receiving with ASIO: Send Succeeds but Receive Fails in Loop
I have the following code set up for receiving and sending messages in UDP using the Asio library.

Note: The Header + Body message being sent is not meant to be
meaningful, I just want to get a clue of at least something being sent
and received over UDP, here I used the Message I made for TCP just to
test.


I can successfully send the message, however, I cannot receive the message while I loop on the UDP::Recieve function.
I started a socket at the 6001 port, as a server, and the 6000 port as a client, then sent the message from the client to the server, specifying the port as 6001. I get the "Send " log from the following code which confirms my sending. But my server, though listening in a loop using the following code, cannot get the message.
void UDP::Recieve(Func inRecieve) {
    mUDPSocket.async_receive(
         asio::buffer(&mTemporaryMessageBuffer.mHeader, sizeof(MessageHeader)),
         [&](std::error_code ec, size_t inSize) {
             if (not ec) {
                 std::cout << "Received:" << inSize << "\n";
                 auto &msg = mTemporaryMessageBuffer;
                 msg.mBody.resize(msg.size());
                 mUDPSocket.async_receive(
                      asio::buffer(mTemporaryMessageBuffer.mBody.data(), msg.mBody.size()),
                      [&](std::error_code ec, size_t inSize) {
                          if (not ec) {
                              std::cout << "Received:" << inSize << "\n";
                              inRecieve(mTemporaryMessageBuffer);
                          } else {
                              std::cout << "ERROR:" << ec.message() << "\n";
                          }
                          std::flush(std::cout);
                      });
             } else {
                 std::cout << "ERROR:" << ec.message() << "\n";
             }
             std::flush(std::cout);
         });
}
void UDP::Send(const Message &inMessage, std::string inDestination, int inPort) {
    asio::ip::udp::endpoint Remote(asio::ip::address::from_string(s(inDestination)), inPort);
    mUDPSocket.async_send_to(asio::buffer(&inMessage.mHeader, sizeof(MessageHeader)),
                             Remote,
                             [&](std::error_code ec, size_t inSize) {
                                 if (not ec) {
                                     std::cout << "Sent" << inSize << "\n";
                                 } else {
                                     std::cout << "ERROR:" << ec.message() << "\n";
                                 }
                                 std::flush(std::cout);
                             });
    mUDPSocket.async_send_to(asio::buffer(inMessage.mBody.data(), inMessage.mBody.size()),
                             Remote,
                             [&](std::error_code ec, size_t inSize) {
                                 if (not ec) {
                                     std::cout << "Sent" << inSize << "\n";
                                 } else {
                                     std::cout << "ERROR:" << ec.message() << "\n";
                                 }
                                 std::flush(std::cout);
                             });
}
} // namespace Jkr::Network


UDP is a connectionless datagram protocol. You're receiving (and sending) the header separately from the body. That's simply not how datagram transport works (UDP transmits full datagrams with no delivery guarantee). Are you sure you didn't want to use TCP?

I know that, I have implemented TCP messaging already. I have a special case for UDP, I am sending the Message I made for TCP just for testing so that I get the clue of at least something being sent with UDP. But here, I am not receiving anything

But, how can you expect the "header" to work at all, if you send it in separate datagrams?

As I commented, there are many issues with the code.
For example, you capture inRecieve by reference, but it's a stack local object, so when you use it in the completion handler you invoke Undefined Behaviour. This alone explains how nothing works reliably.
The naive fix is to capture a copy, and then indeed it ~works~:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/endian/arithmetic.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::udp;
namespace Jkr::Network {
    using Size = boost::endian::big_uint32_t;

    struct MessageHeader {
        Size mId, mSize;
    };

    struct Message {
        MessageHeader     mHeader;
        std::vector<char> mBody;
        size_t            size() const { return mHeader.mSize; }
    };

    class UDP {
      public:
        using Func = std::function<void(Message const&)>;
        UDP(asio::any_io_executor ex, uint16_t port) : mUDPSocket(ex, {{}, port}) {}

        void Recieve(Func inRecieve);
        void Send(Message const& inMessage, std::string inDestination, int inPort);

      private:
        udp::socket mUDPSocket;
        Message     mIncoming;
    };

    void UDP::Recieve(Func inRecieve) {
        mUDPSocket.async_receive(
            asio::buffer(&mIncoming.mHeader, sizeof(MessageHeader)),
            [&, inRecieve = std::move(inRecieve)](std::error_code ec, size_t inSize) {
                if (not ec) {
                    std::cout << "Received:" << inSize << std::endl;
                    mIncoming.mBody.resize(mIncoming.size());
                    mUDPSocket.async_receive( //
                        asio::buffer(mIncoming.mBody),
                        [&, inRecieve = std::move(inRecieve)](std::error_code ec, size_t inSize) {
                            if (not ec) {
                                std::cout << "Received:" << inSize << std::endl;
                                if (inRecieve)
                                    inRecieve(mIncoming);
                            } else {
                                std::cout << "ERROR:" << ec.message() << std::endl;
                            }
                        });
                } else {
                    std::cout << "ERROR:" << ec.message() << std::endl;
                }
            });
    }

    void UDP::Send(Message const& inMessage, std::string inDestination, int inPort) {
        asio::ip::udp::endpoint peer(asio::ip::make_address(inDestination), inPort);

        mUDPSocket.async_send_to( //
            asio::buffer(&inMessage.mHeader, sizeof(MessageHeader)), peer,
            [&](std::error_code ec, size_t inSize) {
                if (not ec) {
                    std::cout << "Sent:" << inSize << std::endl;
                } else {
                    std::cout << "ERROR:" << ec.message() << std::endl;
                }
            });
        mUDPSocket.async_send_to( //
            asio::buffer(inMessage.mBody.data(), inMessage.mBody.size()), peer,
            [&](std::error_code ec, size_t inSize) {
                if (not ec) {
                    std::cout << "Sent:" << inSize << std::endl;
                } else {
                    std::cout << "ERROR:" << ec.message() << std::endl;
                }
            });
    }
} // namespace Jkr::Network

int main() {
    asio::io_context io;
    Jkr::Network::UDP server(io.get_executor(), 6001);
    Jkr::Network::UDP client(io.get_executor(), 6000);

    server.Recieve([](Jkr::Network::Message const& inMessage) {
        fmt::print("Received: header {{{{{},{}}} body {}}}\n", //
                   inMessage.mHeader.mId.value(),              //
                   inMessage.mHeader.mSize.value(),            //
                   inMessage.mBody);
    });

    client.Send({{1, 5}, {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'}}, "127.0.0.1", 6001);
    io.run();
}

Possible output:
Sent:16
Sent:5
Received:16
Received:5
Received: header {{1,5} body ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']}

Local demonstration:

